Is it possible to use env/system variables inside newrelic.yml
I wonder if i can use env/system variables inside of my new relic java agent config. I know that the env variables rewrite the corresponding settings, but i want to use the env variable value inside this yml file (i want to add label based on environment name)

It is for some language agents. Unfortunately for the Java agent it is not possible.
